# Storing JSX code in a variable and rendering it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a welcome screen where the user can decide if they want to login or signup. Using Firebase's onAuthStateChanged, I can check if the User has signed already on this app (the persistence of this "signed in or not" state is local: even if the user closes the app without having signed out they will still be signed in).

**I just want to automatically navigate the user to the home screen (within my stackNavigator) if they are already signed in without rendering (or displaying) anything. How do I do this?**

Since I am a beginner my first thought was to do this conditionally: The screen's returned content would be stored in a variable named *content* and would be null by default. If the user is logged in (tested by the onAuthStateChanged block) it would automatically navigate to the Home screen. If the user isn't logged in content would then be a JSX component (containing two buttons: one to sign up and one to sign in. These buttons both navigate to the appropriate screens)

This hasn't worked so far and my screen is just blank. My code is below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View} from 'react-native';
import WelcomeButtons from "../components/welcomeButtons";
import Firebase from "../fireConfig"

const LoadingScreen = props => {
  let content = null;
  Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("User Signed in")

      props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }else{
      content = (<WelcomeButtons onSignUpPress = {() => props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
      onSignInPress = {() => props.navigation.navigate("Login")}/>);
      console.log("User not signed in")
    }
  });
  
  
    
    return(
      <View>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
}


export default LoadingScreen;
```

**Any approach is welcome, I just need to navigate to the Home screen if the user is logged in before any renders (or at least before displaying anything)**

Comment: a better approach is to use redux to manage the application state including if the user is logged in or not 
and to create diiferent navigation stacks for login area and the actual app
this article will help you achieve your goal :
[link](https://medium.com/@allbitsequal/user-authentification-flow-in-react-native-with-redux-and-navigation-stacks-64450d5f9e0a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged is async function and its take few time to return response but LoadingScreen return response immediately, that's why its show blank screen.
So, Here is solution

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import WelcomeButtons from "../components/welcomeButtons";
import Firebase from "../fireConfig"

const LoadingScreen = props => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
let content = <ActivityIndicator />;
useEffect(() => {
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log("User Signed in")
          props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        }else{
          setLoading(false);
          content = (<WelcomeButtons onSignUpPress = {() => 
           props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
          onSignInPress = {() => props.navigation.navigate("Login")}/>);
          console.log("User not signed in")
        }
      });
  });               
return(
      <View>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
    }
export default LoadingScreen;
```

Comment: Copy pasting this exact code, when the user isn't signed it will load an activity indicator but it will never render the <WelcomeButtons/>. It does console log that the user isn't signed in. Actually it logs that the user isn't signed in twice.